# How to make my controls to appear differently on my wpf application ?

Tags: wpf

I have 3 controls on my part of the gui. 
1. label 
2. textBox
3. button

I want to make the textbox to appear on all the empty space without force the size to be XXX by using Width or MinWidth

Beside this, the button must appear on the left to the textBox

My code ( i try with 2 panel ) :

```
   <!--<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
            <Label  VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Content="Target Folder:" Height="23" />
            <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom"  MinWidth="500" Height="23" />
            <Button VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" Content="..." Height="23" Width="37"  />
        </StackPanel>-->

        <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
            <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Target Folder:" Height="23" />
            <TextBox DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  MinWidth="500" Height="23" />
            <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="..." Height="23" Width="37"  />
        </DockPanel>
```

[image]

Comment: since these things are soooo basic, I would recommend you to read up on the basic `Panel` controls and figure out how they work. For the `DockPanel` for example the order of the child items is important. Also you could have easily done this with a grid with three columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5">
        <Label DockPanel.Dock="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="Target Folder:" Height="23" />            
        <Button DockPanel.Dock="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Content="..." Height="23" Width="37"  />
        <TextBox VerticalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  MinWidth="500" Height="23" />
    </DockPanel>
```